# Selenium 2.20.0 waitForText - No Go

Tags: selenium, junit4

J Unit will not recognize waitForText method.

selenium.waitForText("some random text"); // no go

Any help will be appreciated.

selenium.click("link=some_link"); // works fine

I am trying for that particular piece of text to load from the next page before Selenium performs it's further actions.

Answer (score 1):

I use a loop like so:

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= maxWaitTime) fail("timeout");
    try { if ("Some random text".equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("xyz")).getText())) break; } 
    catch (Exception e) {}
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that selenium supports these types of wait methods. I typically create my own implementation in cases where I have to wait for some asynch event (typically Ajax)

You can basically do it with a loop that executes for as long as IsTextPresent is false.
I recommend adding a timeout in case of an error condition :-)

Comment: I am using the c# API, so it might be different than the JAVA API. However the loop mentioned above should work in Java too though